# Will installing Ubuntu using Wubi have any performance disadvantage compared to a full installation?

Tags: wubi, performance

I wanted to try out Ubuntu. I used Wubi. I really like the appearance and "feel" to it, but it is noticeably slower than my Windows 7. I'm wondering if this is because I am using Wubi instead of a disk. Will it be faster if I use Ubuntu from disk and delete Windows?
I definitely don't want to end up with a slower OS.

Comment: What is noticeably slower? Booting? Loading <some program>? Running <some program>? How much slower is it? Wubi isn't that much slower than a normal install, except for certain file I/O intensive operations (e.g. [de]compression). Sometimes it can run slow if you need a closed-source graphics driver (what graphics card do you have?). More info, more specifics = better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering if this is because I am using Wubi instead of a disk.

Yes it is. Wubi is not a regular installation of Ubuntu. It has its disadvantages. It is more like a virtual installation just to see how Ubuntu is and not measure its performance. If you want to see the real performance you have to install Ubuntu on the Hard Disk Drive or even better on a Solid State Drive (if you have). I recently bought one (SSD) and I installed Ubuntu there, well... the speed and desktop responsiveness are awesome !

What I want to say here is that the performance of an operating system is highly-depended on the Read/Write speeds of the media where it is installed. Imagine Windows 7 on a virtual machine or on `ext4` filesystem.

Read more about [wubi here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide). Ubuntu now it is installed as a Windows application (ouch!) rather than a full operating system.

In my opinion it would be better to test Ubuntu through a USB-stick (even better USB3.0 if you have) rather than wubi.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. I bought a hard disk and am installing now. I was using Wubi as a test, I definitely prefer it to Windows. Also, shortly after I posted this topic, the Wubi Ubuntu became faster.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu will be faster if it is installed on the hard disk as a seperate os rather than from wubi also you need not delete win7 you can dual boot your pc until, atleast, you become comfortable with linux

Answer (score 0):

If u run Ubuntu from a CD then it may run even slower.  But if u install it on ur HDD then it should run great.  Depending on ur computer specs that is.  From what I've seen Ubuntu always runs faster than windows7.

Comment: i think the disk in the question is hdd